# Cannot remove a new line from text

Tags: c#, string

I have this text.There is a new line before `</ul>` tag. So I could't remove that line with this code.

```
str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");
```

But this code is working for just usual string.

```
<ul style="list-style-type&#58;circle;">
  <li><a class="ms - wikilink" href="/Test.aspx">Test1</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this one but didn't help

`Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+", string.Empty);`

Comment: So you want to remove all newLine characters from the input html string, which may looks like the above code, isn't it?

Comment: yeah this `str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");` didn't help.

Comment: How do you get this input html?

Comment: @un-lucky I'll get it from sharepoint page.

Comment: Please show a complete example which we can copy, paste, compile and run ourselves. Also include example input and the output that you get. Describe how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: Check if there is no difference between Environment.NewLine and new line in text. It can be \r\n or \n and in that case replace won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove it with Regex easily

```
Regex.Replace(stringValue, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=>)\s+?(?=<)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var outstr = regex.Replace(YourHTMLString,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the following scenarios

`^$` - which looks for anything that starts and end (no characters) or
`^\s+$` - which looks for any line that starts, has whitespace, and ends

to look for both whithout multiple lookups

`(^$|^\s+$)` - () groups, |  allows an OR statement in searches

`Regex.Replace(content, @"(^$|^\s+$)", String.Empty);` - please bear in mind my C# is rusty, make sure you enable Multiline searching in the regex (usually `/m`)